# how to get the header of a QTableView using the selected indexes?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm dealing with a problem. I have a table created with `QTableView` and `QAbstractTableModel`, which allows to select and copy multiple cells (rows and columns too) setting the extended selection to the `QTableView` `setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);`

This is the function to copy to the `clipboard` the selected cells.

```
bool MyTableView::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event) {
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress ) {
        auto* keyEvent = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_C && (keyEvent->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier)) {
            QModelIndexList cells = selectedIndexes();
            std::sort(cells.begin(), cells.end()); // Necessary, otherwise they are in column order

            QString text;
            int currentRow = 0; // To determine when to insert newlines
            foreach (const QModelIndex& cell, cells) {
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                    // First item
                } else if (cell.row() != currentRow) {
                    // New row
                    text += '\n';
                } else {
                    // Next cell
                    text += '\t';
                }
                currentRow = cell.row();
                text += cell.data().toString();
            }
            QApplication::clipboard()->setText(text);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

The above function allows me to copy only the selected cells from the table to the clipboard, without the header.

Now, I would like to add the header to the clipboard of the selected cells. This is an example of my table, that uses a vertical header (H1, H2, H3, H4):

```
H1 | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
H2 | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  |
H3 | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 |
H4 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
```

For example, If I select and copy the row 1, the expected output is

```
H1 | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
```

If I select and copy the first and last row the expect output is

```
H1 | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
H4 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
```

If I select and copy the first and last column the expected output is:

```
H1 | 0  | 3  |
H2 | 4  | 7  |
H3 | 8  | 11 |
H4 | 12 | 15 |
```

So, as I understand, I should obtain  the `header` from the same list of cells: `QModelIndexList cells = selectedIndexes();`

I add the following loop, before the loop to obtain the header of the selected cells. Whit this I can obtain the corresponding header from each cell

```
foreach (const QModelIndex& cell, cells) {
  auto row = cell.row();
  auto headerText = myTableModel->headerData(row, Qt::Vertical, 
  Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
  std::cout << "header: "<< headerText.toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

But this is incorrect, because as you already notice I'm getting the header for each cell.
I think that the solution could be to identify when a `new row starts` and if the current cell of the loop is the `initial cell` of the row. Any suggestion?, maybe there is an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

What if you write your inner loop like this:

```
[..]
QString text;
int oldRow = -1;
foreach (const QModelIndex& cell, cells) {
    
    const auto row = cell.row();

    if (row != oldRow) {
        if (oldRow != -1) {
            // New row
            text += '\n';
        }
        // Add the header text
        text += myTableModel->headerData(row, Qt::Vertical, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    }
    
    // Next cell
    text += '\t';
    text += cell.data().toString();
    
    oldRow = row;
}
[..]
```

I've slightly modified your version and added header text in the beginning of each line. The new line character is added on switching between rows.